# What is multi-hot encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, encoding, one-hot-encoding

I was read and paper for machine learning, and i found this term "multi-hot encoding" without explanation.
Can you help me please?
the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.06917

Comment: Can you provide the reference to the article?

Comment: Or do you mean „multi“ instead of „mumlti“ https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467633/what-exactly-is-multi-hot-encoding-and-how-is-it-different-from-one-hot

Comment: sure the https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.06917

Comment: I think that answer needs more clarification

Answer (score 0):

Without having read the paper, from the name I would say a multi-hot encoding is a matrix $X \in \{0,1\}^{n \times m }$, with $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_{i,j} = 1, \forall j = 1,\ldots,m$.

You obtain the normal hot-encoding by setting $m=1$.